# Media Query vs Pseudo Class during Fullscreen - CSS Styling Order?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a simple div that I'm styling for responsive design use on smart phones. I'm also using the Fullscreen API so that that div can be made fullscreen, whether on the desktop or mobile.

The mobile version adjust for the menu bar when not in fullscreen with a margin but there is no need for the margin when the div is fullscreen. My implmentation below doesn't appear to work - the margin gets applied both out of full screen and in full screen.

**Edit**: As indicated by Lie Ryan's answer below, I was make the parent of myDiv fullscreen and the fullscreen pseudo class is only available to the element that is fullscreen.

```
.myDiv
{
    width: 80%;
}

    .myDiv:-webkit-full-screen
    {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .myDiv:-moz-full-screen
    {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .myDiv:-ms-full-screen
    {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .myDiv
    {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    .myDiv
    {
        margin-top: 65px;
    }
}
```

**Q: What is the order in which CSS media queries and pseudo classes are applied? How do I style my div so that when the div goes full screen, the margin is removed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I think I see what your question is now. The full-screen pseudo-selector are applied to the item that you're requesting to full screen not to the myDiv. Compare the three full screens in [this jsfiddle (Firefox only)](http://fiddle.jshell.net/72Th8/7/show/), only the first one have the full screen rule applied.

**OLD ANSWER:**

> Q: What is the order in which CSS media queries and pseudo classes are applied? How do I style my div so that when the div goes full screen, the margin is removed?

Rules with the same selector specificity cascades; i.e. later rules overrides earlier rules.

Rules with higher selector specificity overrules rules with lower selector specifity. Selector specificity is a fairly complex topic; but the short version is: #id overrules .class overrules tagname overrules * selector. Also, inline styles (i.e. style= attribute) overrules embedded styles (e.g. `<style>` tag inside `<head>`) which overrules external styles (i.e. styles linked using `<link>`).

Neither media query or fullscreen API changes the cascade or specifity rule.

Comment: To summarize: the fullscreen pseudo class can only be used on the element what was made fullscreen. If myDiv is made fullscreen, then myDiv will have .myDiv:fullscreen available to it.

Comment: @Dragonseer: you can also use a bare `:-*-full-screen .myDiv`, which would make the rule usable when any of the parents of .myDiv is made full screen.